# How can I get TypeScript to automatically infer the type of the result of a `yield` call?

Tags: typescript, generator, type-inference, yield

In the following code example:

```
function* gen() {
    let v = yield Promise.resolve(0);
    return v;
}
```

The type of `v` is inferred to be `any`. I'm wondering if there's a way to get it to infer a different type (say, `number`) based on contextual clues.

I know that in this specific scenario I can use `async`/`await` instead, but I'm wondering about the general case (when not working with promises).

Comment: While the type of `v` inside the function is `any`, if I check the value of the returned value: `let a = gen()` I get `IterableIterator<Promise<number>>` which seems about right.

Comment: The value of `v` is provided by the client who's calling your routine (in the `.next()` call); many clients could in theory call it with many different types, so by definition there is no way for TypeScript to infer the type, even assuming it was able do complete static analysis on all the places your generator is being called from.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Unfortunately, Typescript just doesn't support this right now.  And there doesn't really appear to be a good workaround other than simply putting a type annotation on every `yield` statement:

```
function* gen() {
    let v: number = yield Promise.resolve(0);
    return v;
}
```

It's a tricky problem to solve, as the value returned by `yield` statements is entirely dependent on the semantics of whatever is consuming the generator.  I know that `yield Promise.resolve(0)` will eventually return a number only because I know the semantics of `coroutine`, but `v` really could be anything.

But hopefully Typescript will add support for declaring these relationships as part of the type of the generator itself.  Here's a [relevant github issue](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/32523).